# Do I need a visa when travelling through Brussels from South Africa

Tags: visas, brussels

We are travelling to the UK from South Africa and I have a UK visa, but do I need a transit visa for Brussels, Belgium for a technical stop over?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: There are flights to the UK that make a technical stop in Belgium? Do you actually mean technical stop (essentially, the plane stopping to refuel) or is this just a regular connecting flight?